# Confusion about the structure of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, clauses, sentence-usage

I confronted with this sentence:

> Rainfall was limited and **what water there was rushed across the plain in the annual flood of melted snow**.

I'm confused with the sentence in bold. Can anyone help explain the structure of that sentence? Thanks!

Comment: [what water (that) there was] = subject clause; [rushed across the plain in the annual flood of melted snow] = predicate

Comment: @Clare So there is an attributive clause inside the subject clause? Is it typical in English?

Comment: It is not atypical. Consider an average, everyday  sentence with a similar structure acting as the direct object: *I threw [what garbage (that)  there was] into the large trash can*.

Comment: The sentence is fine and well-written. It consists of an independent clause with a passive meaning. The subject is "What water there was", and the predicate is the passive verb phrase "was rushed across the plain in the annual flood of melted snow". "What" is a fused determinative here in the noun phrase "what water". Determinative "what" implies a relatively small amount, so the sentence can be paraphrased as _The little water that was available was vigorously pushed across the plain in the annual flood ..._

Comment: @BillJ  If "what water" is used is a noun phrase, then the sentence structure should be "[what water] [(that) there was] rushed across the plain in the annual flood of melted snow"  But you said the predicate is the passive verb phrase "was rushed across the plain in the annual flood of melted snow". I'm confused with the **passive** verb phrase in the predicate (since "was" is already used in "there was").

Comment: "That" is optional here.. The complement of "was" ("What water") has been fronted, but we understand "there was what water" (cf. "there was little water"). So the sentence is [what water there was __ ] [was rushed across the plain in the annual flood of melted snow], where __ represents the complement of "was".

Comment: @BillJ Thank you! I got your point, but the original sentence is  "what water there **was** rushed ..." and according to your explanation the sentence should be "what water there **was was** rushed ...". Is the "was"  duplicated?

Comment: Sorry, llxxee; I misread the sentence. It's not a passive clause at all. There is only one "was", which is part of the subject, so it is: [what water there was __ ] [rushed across the plain in the annual flood of melted snow]. "Rushed" is a past tense verb-form, not a past participle, so no passive here.

Comment: @BillJ, what's with the commenting? What you said looks like a superb answer; why not make it one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**what water there was** = the water which was available, in spite of the limited rainfall. It is the subject in the sentence in bold.

**rushed** = the verb

**across the plain** = where it rushed

**in the annual flood of melted snow** = when it rushed = when the snow melted (i.e. the spring of each year)